# Iterate through array of objects and print out property value

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, hasownproperty

If I have this:

```
  myArr = [{name: 'rich', secondName: 'james'}, {name: 'brian', secondName: 'chris'}];

  mySecondArr = [];
```

how can I loop over this so that `mySecondArr = ['rich', 'brian']`

I was thinking of doing something like:

```
for (var key in myArr){
    if (Object.hasOwnProperty(name){
      mySecondArr.push(name[value])
}
```

I know that is pseudo code but cant quite thing of the syntax for doing this as simply as possible

NO JQUERY PLEASE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
for (var i=0;i<myArr.length; i++){
    if (myArr[i].name!=undefined){
      mySecondArr.push(myArr[i].name)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use map like this :

```js
var myArr = [{name: 'rich', secondName: 'james'}, {name: 'brian', secondName: 'chris'}];

var mySecondArr = myArr.map(x => x.name);
console.log(mySecondArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `map` function and return the `secondName`

```
var result = myArr.map(function(a) {return a.secondName;});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) (ES6 code):

```js
var myArr = [{name: 'rich', secondName: 'james'}, {name: 'brian', secondName: 'chris'}];

var mySecondArr = myArr.map(o => o.name);

console.log(mySecondArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
 var myArr = [{ name: 'rich', secondName: 'james' }, { name: 'brian', secondName: 'chris' }];

        var mySecondArr = [];

        myArr.forEach(function (data, index, myArr) {
            debugger;
            mySecondArr.push(data.name);
        });

        alert(mySecondArr);
```